# gtsummary::tbl_summary() how to change statistics

Tags: r

**EDIT: Problem solved thanks to Susan Switzer, the code is fine it was just an issue with an older version of R/gtsummary.**

I want to manipulate the statistics in a `gtsummary` table. It seems very straightforward. However, for some reason, when pasting the default of `statistic` (see text below) I get an error.

My code:

```
iris %>% gtsummary::tbl_summary(
  statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)")
)
```

The error message:

```
Error in `statistic=` argument input. Select from ‘Sepal.Length’, ‘Sepal.Width’, ‘Petal.Length’, ‘Petal.Width’, ‘Species’
```

And her is the documentation of the statistic argument:

```
List of formulas specifying types of summary statistics to display for each vari- able. The default is list(all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"). See below for details.
```

It seems very stupid and simple, what I am missing? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I am using gtsummary 1.6.2 and do not see the error. The code runs fine to proceed a gtsummary table.

Comment: Thank you! Thought I suddenly became really really stupid for about half an hour. Now updated everything and it runs just fine. Should have thought of that.

Comment: We are all in this together! Happy to hear that you are off and running again.